# Python (replace multiple values from different columns using replace)

Tags: python

I have a data frame with different columns.One column x has value "a" and other column y has value "b", can I replace both values simultaneously using replace?

I can do it by two statments like

```
df["x"]=df["x"].replace("a","not a")
df["y"]=df["y"].replace("b","not b")
```

It works fine but can I do it in one statement like -

```
df["x","y"]=df["x","y"].replace(["a","b"],["not a","not b"]) ?
```

Comment: You can replace a string with a string, with another string by chaining another replace to the end.. Not sure how would you describe your suggestion..

Comment: Are they changing to the same value? Why does it need to be on one line? I think this will run the risk of losing readability.

Answer (score 1):

To index by multiple columns, create a list inside of the indexing operator. Note that the replace method on a DataFrame will replace every occurrence in all the columns (so it may behave differently if you have 'a' values in both columns but only wanted to replace in one of them).

```
df[['x', 'y']] = df[['x', 'y']].replace({'a':'not a','b':'not b'})
```

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: I did with list instead of passing dictionary, even that is working. What is the difference if we pass dictionary or list as input in replace?